# ForEach<Array<Unit>, Int, Text>: the ID 1 occurs multiple times within the collection, this will give undefined results

Tags: sqlite, swiftui

I'm making a HTTP request to a REST API I created which contains two tables in the DBMS, the main table is called Levels looks like this

Levels:

leve_id: 1
level: "Level 1"

I have a child table called Units that looks like this

Units:

primary_id: 1
unit: "Unit 1"
unit_id: 1 ,foreign key to level_id

I have inserted "unit 1" and "unit 2" to this table and they both have the unit_id: equal to 1 because I want them in Level 1.

Now, the problem is when I'm trying to use a forEach loop in swiftUI to show the units.

struct UnitView: View {
@StateObject var unitVm = UnitViewModel()

```
var body: some View {
    
    List(unitVm.units, id:\.idUnit){ unit in
        Text(unit.unit)
    }
}
```

}

It gives me an error of "ID 1 occurs multiple times"
Which is understandable since the foreign keys aren't unique,
could anyone point me in the right direction to show multiple units with the same id in a particular level?

Comment: An is being unique is required by SwiftUI. Without an identify that SwiftUI can track it doesn’t know when to load views.

Comment: You could assign unique IDs to the items you get back from the REST API as they come in.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what data you're working with, exactly, in terms of the UnitViewModel, but I'm guessing that it's a direct translation of the Units table, ie with four fields corresponding to: primary_id, unit, unit_id, and level_id.

For the purposes of the swiftUI List, it just needs each item to be uniquely identifiable (eg when you say scrollTo(someItemID)), so you should just supply it the path to your primary_id (which I assume is unique for the whole table) and all should work well. It won't care about the duplicates in idUnit, at that point.